# Load Capistrano's environment in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

What's the best way to load the Capistrano environment within the rails console?

I'd like to access the variables and methods capistrano is using in deploys such as latest_release,  source etc.

Ruby debug isn't efficient when trying to hack out complicated capistrano tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the Rails console is probably not practical as the two environments would likely come into conflict. In an interactive console isn't hard, though. You could add a Capistrano task that simply spins up one:

```
task :console do
  require 'irb'
  $config = self
  ARGV.clear
  IRB.start
end
```

This exposes the current configuration object as the global `$config`. Although using a global variable is a bit ugly, I couldn't find a way to switch the default context of IRB from the `main` object.

Comment: this works perfectly once I realized using $config will give me everything I need.  I wonder if there's a way to set the main object class in irb to the default class.  Guess that's what pry is for

Comment: Hi! Did you get how to change the context of IRB inside capistrano? Im trying to get all role names defined on a capistrano. I havent found any document related to this. You re the only one talking about ir. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RenatoIsidio That'd involve exploring the current Capistrano API, which I'm not intimately familiar with, however, the source itself should give you an idea of where to look.